# Children's room in Chinese

Tags: vocabulary

I have a homework to describe my apartment. How do you call a children's room in Chinese? Is it common to have a room for kids in China? Looking through possible combinations of 孩子，房间，and 间 in the dictionary I couldn't come up with something decent.

Comment: We say 儿童房 in my site.

Answer (score 5):

A children's room would be called 儿童房(er2 tong2 fang2), and if you happen to want to say nursery, if the word nursery happens to fit the use of the room, it would be 保育室 (bao3 yu4 shi4).